Jest encountered an unexpected token, In React app
I'm trying to run the test case for the app. But its showing below error. Can someone help me to clear the issue.
Attaching the code repo.
https://github.com/Arun12Muralidharan/team_tracker

I can't modify package.json, Test/* test*js, *sh
Its using below node & npm version, in web ide (execution part) $ node -v v8.15.1 $ npm -v
6.4.1

FAIL  src/Tests/AddMember.test.js
● Test suite failed to run
Jest encountered an unexpected token

This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

Here's what you can do:
 • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
 • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
 • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

Details:

/projects/challenge/node_modules/cheerio/dist/commonjs/api/attributes.js:300
        catch {
              ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

  4 | // learn more: https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom
  5 | // import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
> 6 | import { configure } from "enzyme";
    | ^
  7 | import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
  8 | configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
  9 |

  at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:537:17)
  at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:579:25)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/cheerio/src/cheerio.ts:6:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/cheerio/src/load.ts:7:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/cheerio/src/load-parse.ts:1:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/cheerio/src/index.ts:6:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/enzyme/src/Utils.js:9:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/enzyme/src/ReactWrapper.js:4:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/enzyme/src/index.js:1:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/setupTests.js:6:1)
      at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)

FAIL  src/Tests/Login.test.js
● Test suite failed to run
Jest encountered an unexpected token

This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

Here's what you can do:
 • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
 • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
 • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

Details:

/projects/challenge/node_modules/cheerio/dist/commonjs/api/attributes.js:300
        catch {
              ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

  4 | // learn more: https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom
  5 | // import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
> 6 | import { configure } from "enzyme";
    | ^
  7 | import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
  8 | configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

  at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:537:17)
  at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:579:25)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/cheerio/src/cheerio.ts:6:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/cheerio/src/load.ts:7:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/cheerio/src/load-parse.ts:1:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/cheerio/src/index.ts:6:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/enzyme/src/Utils.js:9:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/enzyme/src/ReactWrapper.js:4:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/enzyme/src/index.js:1:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/setupTests.js:6:1)
      at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)


Links to third party websites are only allowed in addition to having the [mcve] in your post. If folks can't answer your question from what's in your post alone, your post is incomplete (and note that the minimal example requires some work on your part - that's intentional. It's part of learning to properly debug, and more often than not, you find the problem while trying to minimize, so you end up not even needing to post to SO)

Are you actually on node 8? How is that possible? That's a 7 year old version of node!

(also on a repo note: why on earth are you using .sh scripts when package.json already offers script functionality, there is literally no reason for test.sh to exist when npm test exists, just turn those test steps into npm tasks and make "test" run those =)

It's a part of web ide mini project.. I guess it was created very long ago, so it's using node v8.

tesh.sh is used to evaluate the score from that project. Its a mini project to evaluate the skill.

I had found the issue. One of the dependency wasn't compatible.
cheerio - 1.0.0 wasn't working as expected.
cheerio - 1.0.0-rc.12 will work & make the test case to run.

In short this is happening because as of cheerio v1.0.0 the project has switched over to ES Modules and enzyme is not compatible with this version. Adding this to your package.json should work:
"overrides": {
    "enzyme": {
      "cheerio": "1.0.0-rc.3"
    }
  }


I believe this is only possible starting npm 8. But the OP uses 6.4

I almost missed the true answer in the context of using node 8 and npm < 8 in one of the comments from OP:

Upgrade cheerio to version 1.0.0-rc.12

It worked for me too. And sorry to still having projects using node 8, it is not so easy to upgrade (and in my case it would be faster to trash the code and recode from scatch, but I don't have the funding)

I also tried with latest version of cheerio (1.0.0 so far) but did not work
